# WPF C# Resource Cannot Be Found

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Just started to WPF with C# and VS Community 2017. Tried to run code that will change the start up window.
but get  the following exception.

```
System.IO.IOException: 'Cannot locate resource 'application_startup'.'
```

this code is from the App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="StartUp_Window.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StartUp_Window"
         StartupUri="Application_Startup">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

This is from the App.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace c
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class App : Application
  {
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create the startup window 
        MainWindow wnd = new MainWindow();
        // Do stuff here, e.g. to the window 
        wnd.Title = "Something else for fs";

           // Show the window 
           wnd.Show();
    }

  }
}
```

this is from the MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="StartUp_Window.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StartUp_Window"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

this is also from the MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace StartUp_Window
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the new error that comes up after changing the startupuri in App.xaml file.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'App' does not contain a definition for 'Application_Startup' and no extension method 'Application_Startup' accepting a first argument of type 'App' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   StartUp_Window  C:\Users\faisal\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WPF_Tutorial\StartUp_Window\StartUp_Window\App.xaml   5   Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MainWindow' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    StartUp_Window  C:\Users\faisal\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WPF_Tutorial\StartUp_Window\StartUp_Window\App.xaml.cs    20  Active
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MainWindow' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    StartUp_Window  C:\Users\faisal\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WPF_Tutorial\StartUp_Window\StartUp_Window\App.xaml.cs    20  Active

Comment: https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/wpf-application/command-line-parameters/

Answer (score 4):

In the App.xaml, this line here:

```
StartupUri="Application_Startup"
```

should be:

```
Startup="Application_Startup"
```

Edit: As @AQuirky mentioned, you should make StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml".

Comment: Also need StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"

Comment: @AQuirky where do i fix your line

Comment: @AQuirky, your assertion that StartupUri is required is incorrect. If you are using a startup method like the OP is wanting to do, then setting the apps main window in code is sufficient and possibly desire if you have a couple of different windows that could be displayed based on startup args or settings/user profiles etc.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `StartupUri` attribute from `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="StartUp_Window.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StartUp_Window">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

...and *override* the  `OnStartup` method in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        // Create the startup window 
        MainWindow wnd = new MainWindow();
        // Do stuff here, e.g. to the window 
        wnd.Title = "Something else for fs";

        // Show the window 
        wnd.Show();

    }
}
```

Or set the `StartupUri` property to the name of your window:

```
<Application x:Class="StartUp_Window.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StartUp_Window"
         StartupUri="MainWindow">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

...and do nothing in `App.xaml.cs`.

Comment: when I change the startupuri from 
StartupUri="Application_Startup"   to  Startup="Application_Startup" I get an error. The error is pasted above

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't change it. You should remove it. Didn't you read my answer? Read it again then. Override the OnStartup method and remove StartupUri from App.xaml.

Comment: @MM8, The option in which there is no Startup or StartupUri in XAML I do not recommend using.
In this case, the App resources are not initialized and may lead to a bug.